# SQL Server 2008 Login user mapping does not persist

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to grant a domain user to SQL Server 2008. This user should be able to login to the DB using server management studio, and run PowerShell scripts doing SELECT queries to a database. My problem is my settings does not persist.

In server management studio, I right click on Security->Logins->right click on ->Properties->User mappings-> tick my database which happens to be the first one, granted 'db_datareader' and 'public'.
Click OK.

No error pops up.
But when I check the user mappings again, my database is no longer ticked! What have I missed? Really puzzled... must be something very simple...

[image]

--update--:

soved: deleted the login+user, added them back,and the rest.. now ok. many thx!

Comment: Have you tried scripting it out and then running to see if there are any warnings/errors that SSMS may not have handled for some reason?

Comment: @mservidio Tried that, no error, still not persisted. In the end I deleted the user and login, add it back, now it is ok. But thanks for this, I did not think of scripting it out..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
use master;
GO

create login [<domain\user>] from windows;
GO

use [<yourdb>];
GO

create user [<domain\user>] for login [<domain\user>];
GO

ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [<domain\user>];
GO
```

Comment: Thanks! I am making a note of your script.. It turned out to be glitch. I deleted the user and login, re-added them and granted to privileges, all done from management studio, the same way I did before, now it is ok. dont know why the settings did not persist..

Comment: I changed last line, according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187750(v=sql.110).aspx) doc, the sp_ is or will be deprecated.

Answer (score 7):

It happens sometimes when user has no connect permission or the permission has been revoked.

```
Grant connect to [user]
```